# Proving that $G$ is a hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

> Consider the set $P_n$ of all polynomials of degree $\le n$ with complex coefficients. Any such polynomial $p$ can be represented as a coefficient vector $[p]\in \Bbb C^{n+1}$ via $$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \Longleftrightarrow [p] = \left[\begin{matrix}a_0 \\a_1\\ \vdots \\a_n \end{matrix}\right]$$
> Suppose we define an inner product on polynomials as $(p,q) = \int_{-1}^1 \overline{p(x)} q(x)dx$. Thus, two polynomials $p,q$ are orthogonal if $\int_{-1}^1 \overline{p(x)} q(x)dx = 0$.
>
> **(a)** Show that there exists a Hermitian matrix $G$ such that $(p,q) = [p]^*G[q]$ for all polynomials $p,q\in P_n$.

---

I know that that this is the polynomial analogue of QR factorization, but I cannot see how to get started. I thought of proving the general definition by somehow but I don't understand how to deal with the LHS that is $(p,q)$.

Comment: Picture questions are not cool. If you expect people to think about your homework, please follow the rules.

Comment: @IgorRivin This seems like a new user, so I have converted the question from picture to MathJax for them.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine You are a more selfless man than I.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Thank you very much! I'm not very well versed with MathJax to quickly convert this question, but I'll make sure that my next questions are properly written.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the community! :) @AnonymousNinja

Answer (score 2):

You can write down the inner product explicitly. What is $(x^n, x^m)?$ It will be the $n,m$ entry of your mysterious $G.$

Comment: I can see how that is true but how do I prove that G is hermitian from that? (I'm kinda new to linear algebra as well, math is not my major :/)